# Resharper method call "At end of line" formatting style

Tags: resharper

Resharper has a lot of formatting settings, but I didn't manage to find method call parentheses layout options.

The goal is to preserve this kind of formatting:

```
CallFooMethod(
    parameter1,
    parameter2,
    parameter3
);
```

But after putting a semicolon or calling cleanup i'm always getting this:

```
CallFooMethod(
    parameter1,
    parameter2,
    parameter3
    );
```

Does anyone know the way to solve this? Maybe there is a way to intervene in a formatting process with some ReSharper's API for extensions?

Comment: The top way more closely follows the normal convention of how these are formatted. Is there a specific reason you want the bottom way?

Comment: Vise versa - I want it to be the top way, but there is no way to preserve it. Even if you do this manually resharper will change it to the bottom indentation style.